# Регулярные выражения запрет символов в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать regex, в котором будут запрещены такие символы `!@#$%^&*()_`, но запрещены они должны быть при любых обстоятельствах, не только когда вводишь только их, но и когда они попадаются в середине слова, например `V@sya` или `Dimon#`. У меня получилось только написать условие когда строка содержит только эти символы, например `#@!` но если добавить любой разрешенный символ, например `A#@!` - тогда уже регулярка не срабатывает. Подскажите, как можно реализовать проверку чтобы не только одни спец. символы проверялись, но и их наличие в середине слова с допустимыми символами ?

На всякий случай мой regex:

`ValidationExpression="^(?![\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-\+\!\@\#\$\^\*\)\(]+$).+"`

Использую в Asp.Net WebForms

Код:

```
User name: <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UserNameValidator" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid User Name" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(?![\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-\+\!\@\#\$\^\*\)\(]+$).+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так.

```
[^!@#$%^&*()_]
```

Символ `^`, стоящий на первом месте внутри квадратных скобок, означает исключение всех последующих символов из соответствия регулярному выражению.

[Раздел на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D1.8B_.28.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.29)

> Если требуется указать символы, которые не входят в указанный набор, то используют символ `^` внутри квадратных скобок, например `[^0-9]` означает любой символ, кроме цифр.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, `ValidationExpression="^[^!@#$%^&*()_]$"` - вот это не то что вам нужно?

Comment: @iksuy, у вас регулярка соответствует одному одному символу. И в комментарии вы дали вариант на строку размером в один символ.

Answer (score 1):

ValidationExpression="^[^\%/\\&\?\,\'\;:!-+!@#\$\^*)(]{1,50}$" где {1,50} минимальная и максимальная длина строки.

Answer (score 1):

```
const isForbiddenSymbol = /^(?=.*[!@#$%^&(),.+=/\/\]\[{}?><":;|])/;

console.log('isForbiddenSymbol', isForbiddenSymbol.test(control.value));
```